# Pulling previous Artifactory builds into Jenkins workspace for use in comparing SHA-256 hashes

Tags: maven, jenkins, artifactory, sha256

I am using maven 3 to build in Jenkins and publish to Artifactory.  At build, I run a shell to calculate SHA-256 hashes on the workspace.  We need to use Jenkins to deploy these builds.  Is there a way to pull a particular build from Artifactory into Jenkins without changing the metadata for Maven?  I just want to pull the build into the Jenkins workspace, re-run the SHA-256 and compare the results.

Comment: I've built a maven project in Jenkins, pulled the source via git tag then did and install with -D=build.number={the build I want}.

Comment: This pulls the correct revision from git, but the meta data is modified via maven install, so the has routine run via shell contains a different value with the workspace.